# Resize Image inside ImageView, then resize imageView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview

I have a big square drawable image that I want to display in an `ImageView` 
that is small since it has to `match_parent` a `LinearLayout` in *height*. 
I want the image to be resized in *width* also, keeping the image's aspect ratio. 
So I have something like:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

   <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:src="@drawable/image"/>

   <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I expect is that the linearlayout measures the *height* of the `TextView`, 
then the `ImageView` gets this *height* and finally rescales its *width* to keep image aspect ratio.

Instead, the `ImageView` width doesn't rescale and what I have in the end is an `ImageView` with the correct *height* 
(measured through the `TextView` *height*) but the *width* of the original, not scaled, drawable image.

It seems that `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` 
isn't working and the *width* initially set to `wrap_content` of a not scaled image is kept until the end.

Where I'm wrong? And how to get the `ImageView` rescaled as I want?

Comment: did you try android:scaleType="fitXY"?

Comment: @Ravi Gadipudi Yes, the result is that the imageview keep the same width but the image is streched and destorted horizontally...

Comment: try drawableleft in text view

Comment: textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: also try scaleType `centerCrop` or `fitCenter`.